# How to check if Android Studio is properly installed?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just somehow installed Android Studio on my PC with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using some 'here&there' guides on internet. But I am not sure if it will work correctly OR if is installed properly.

Is there any way to check and confirm the same? I am asking this because I will be out of the town for some days without proper internet. So I don't want any kind of download related interruptions. Please see and help.

Comment: It is almost impossible to determine from what you posted. Try running it

Comment: Be aware that android-studio downloads things "on the fly" depending on what you are doing, what android version you are testing with etc. It downloads from dl.google.com which does not work behind a "captive network" ie. the sort of public wifi that gives you a login page the first time you use it. Fine if you are a pro sitting in an office with good wifi bit otherwise...

Answer (score 1):

> But I am not sure if it will work correctly OR is it installed
>   properly ?

Try below steps to find out:-

1. Open terminal
2. Navigate to `android-studio/bin/ directory`
3. Execute `studio.sh`, by typing `./studio.sh`

Comment: As such the whole application is loading full fledge. I am able to load new project and can see all greens (at bottom where files load).

Comment: It means Android Studio is installed probably :)

Comment: Please accept my answer if this helped

Comment: How to do that ? I am newbie here.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Its working fine.